# os.walk thinks my directory contains only .DS_Store files

Tags: python, os.walk

This is confusing! For some reason, `os.walk` is telling me that all I have is a file structure full of `.DS_Store` files, which is not true.

```
alist = []

for root, directories, filenames in os.walk('/somedir/full/of/subdirs/and_PDFs'):
    somelist.append(os.path.join(root,filename))
```

So, `alist[0:5]` gives me a sample:

```
['.DS_Store',
 '/somedir/full/of/subdirs/and_PDFs/0008/.DS_Store',
 '/somedir/full/of/subdirs/and_PDFs/0008/18/.DS_Store',
 '/somedir/full/of/subdirs/and_PDFs/0027/.DS_Store',
 '/somedir/full/of/subdirs/and_PDFs/0027/41/.DS_Store']
```

I have no idea why os.walk thinks all I've got are `.DS_Store` files?

(I should also add, the whole `alist` is full of these, not just the first 5.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is using `filename` (maybe defined earlier somewhere in the code), not `filenames`. You need to iterate `filenames` to get files (Iterate `directories` also if you want directory names too)

```
alist = []

for root, directories, filenames in os.walk('/somedir/full/of/subdirs/and_PDFs'):
    for fn in filenames:
        alist.append(os.path.join(root,fn))
```